# Wpf handling exception throwing by task

Tags: c#, wpf, task-parallel-library

How can i handle an exception on wpf, that was throwed within worker thread?

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void MainWindow_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Hello");
            throw new Exception();
        });

        try
        {
            task.Wait();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }

    }
}
```

Or it is not common to handle an exception in this way?

Comment: Can you not use `async/await`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can catch the `[System.AggregateException]` to examine if you can handle any of its [InnerExceptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.aggregateexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). See the example below.

```
var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Hello");
    throw new InvalidOperationException(); // throw an InvalidOperationException that is handled.
});

try
{
    task.Wait();
}
catch (AggregateException ae)
{
    ae.Handle((x) =>
    {
        if (x is InvalidOperationException) // We know how to handle this exception.
        {
            Console.WriteLine("InvalidOperationException error.");
            return true; // Continue with operation.
        }
        return false; // Let anything else stop the application.
    });
}
```

Comment: This will block the UI with `task.Wait()`.

Comment: @zero_coding what for to use Wait in UI code behind? No reason to use TPL if you block UI as Noseratio said

Comment: No, is not gonna block, because i let the error handling work on a seperate thread.

Comment: @zero_coding, at least in the code from your question it will. You block with `task.Wait()` on the UI thread inside `MainWindow_OnLoaded` even handler. Instead, make `MainWindow_OnLoaded` `async` and do `await task`.

Comment: yes now i see, i use the example from Artiom. it works well. `task.ContinueWith(t =>`

Answer (score 3):

```
task.ContinueWith(task => {
      if (task .Exception != null)
                    {
                        //.........
                    }

},TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
```

Take a look here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/152765/Task-Parallel-Library-of-n#handlingExceptions

Comment: i had try it already and it does not work i got the msg: An exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in WpfMultiThreadException.exe but was not handled in user code

Comment: updateed the answer. you have to access the Exception property, in this case it will be handled. I thought you will insert your code in mine